# Load image from a file inside a project folder

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to load an image from a file without using a `FileChooser`.
The folders are:

```
TestProject
-src
--application
---(all_the_classes_i'm_using.java)
-assets
--drawIcon.png
```

I want to load the image in the assets folder.
I've tried:

```
Image image = new Image("../assets/drawIcon.png")
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../assets/drawIcon.png"))
```

I've tried it with the string path "/TestProject/assets/drawIcon.png", but nothing. I don't understand how to load this image!

Comment: Try `new Image(getClass().getResource("/assets/drawIcon.png").toExternalForm());`

Comment: Is the `assets` folder on `classpath`?

Comment: Never use `..` with getResource.  If you package your application in a jar (which is pretty standard), then the resource will be accessible because `..` is not recognized by the jar access protocol.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the `assets` directory as a resource directory and then load the image as a resource from the location "/drawIcon.png":

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/drawIcon.png");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

In case you want to create a javafx Image:

```
Image image = new Image("/drawIcon.png");
```

In this case, also, mark that folder as resource folder.

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html

Comment: `ImageIO.read(...)` returns a `java.awt.Image`, not a `javafx.scene.image.Image`, as I assume is required here (note tags).

Comment: How do I set assets directory as a resource directory?

Comment: Depends on your IDE / build system. Do you use Intellij Idea? Or maven?

Answer (score 3):

You can use getResource(path).toString();
the path must start with /, and it starts with the verry first package in your src folder.

`Image img= new Image(getClass().getResource("/path/in/your/package/structure/icon.png").toString());`