# How to set objects path to the app directory

Tags: java, swing

I compiled my app with image objects, which located in my computer

```
ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("D:\\pictures\\background.png")
```

It seems to be unseen , as soon as I change location of my pictures. Then, I copied those images in app folder and I don’t know how to set path for them. The Idea is to set path of the images for JavaFx application, which should locate at the same folder. And when my app is in someone’s computer,system should know that the pictures inside application folder , wherever this folder locates. 
Thanks in advance

---

Here I’ve made some changes based on advice.

I added my images directly to the project folder by creating new packages resources.images and dragging images in it. 
Then I created `BufferedImage img;` and set path  for every image I needed

```
  Image bg;
Image fg;
Image object;
img  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(“resources/images/img1.png”));
bg = img;
img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(“resources/images/img2.png”));
  fg  = img;
```

And so on ...
Then I drew these images through paintComponent. 
And everything seems to be fine, it works after compiling in my environment as it should , but as soon as I create JavaFx app and run .exe file , images don’t display, just empty frame.
:( help me deal with this guys. Thx

Comment: You may not possess the required access there. Alternatively, consider `getResource()`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29780369/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to use images that **you** define and then use those images on whatever computer your app is running. If that is what you are trying to do, I suggest the following:

Create a package called for instance 'images' in one of your source folders.

Access it with

```
ImageIO.read(YourMainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/imagename.png"));
```

(`ImageIO.read` is just an example of a way to load an image, use whatever you like.)
If you export your app correctly, the images should be put into the jar and be accessible for your application on any device.

Comment: Should I create Image image = ImageIO.read(myClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(“\\mypict.png”)? How it looks like

Comment: You will have to put that line of code in a try catch to catch an eventual IOException, but everything else seems good. the ImageIO.read is guaranteed to return a BufferedImage, so you could also declare the image as a BufferedImage, but that is not required.

Comment: yeah, but problem is that images still unseen when I run my app using .exe. I suppose jar wasn’t generated, and app can’t see images. They are put into environment in separate package , and can be used by compiler during debugging. But app isn’t working properly outside environment:(

Comment: Wait... your application is an .exe file? I was expecting that your application would be a .jar file. If that were the case, the image should have been put in the jar. So how does your .exe structure look like?

Comment: I said that I created JavaFx application, and using IntelliJ IDEA in project structure added new artifact, and then after filling all appropriate fields environment compiled and generated folder with .exe file, which I want to add to archive and send to anybody. That’s was an idea. So now app works well only in my environment, but not outside.

Comment: Note that getClass().getResource is not exactly the same as getClass().getClassLoader().getResource. I remember once having a problem because of this. If changing that doesn't solve your problem, you could open up your .exe with something like 7zip and see if your images are there and in which directory.

Comment: it even doesn’t compile with getClassLoader() :(

Comment: That's very weird, what is the exact code for loading it via the class loader?

Comment: now is ok, I made a mistake , set wrong path to directory where finished app should locate during compilation, and used previously compiled .exe file instead. It’s working properly right now . Finally using BufferImage with ImageIO getClass getResource helped.